# auto switch toggle off if one is currently on

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

there are nested toggle buttons which are off by default, when user turns one on it saves a value to localstorage. What i want to do is when one is turned on and you try to turn the other on, the first one should be turned off automatically while the other turns on.

JS

```
.controller('shops',['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope,$http,$timeout){
$http.get('http://localhost/work/templates/source.php').success(function(data){
       $scope.shops=data ;

        });

 $scope.active_shop = {};
  $scope.active_shop.checked = false;
  $scope.active_shop = function(item) {
        if($scope.active_shop.checked){
            localStorage.setItem("shop_id",($scope.item.shop_id));
        }else{
             localStorage.removeItem("shop_id");
         }

  }
}])
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-controller="shops" ng-repeat="item in shops">
          <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap"> 
          <img src="img/index/fashion.png" alt="photo" width="32" height="32" />
          <h2>{{item.shop_name}} </h2>
          <p>{{item.biz_location}}</p>

    <input type="hidden" value="{{item.shop_id}}">

          <div align="right">
          <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
          <input type="checkbox"ng-model="active_shop.checked" ng-change="active_shop()">
          <div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div> 
          </label>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          </div>
```

I'm finding it hard to put the second js into the first one. I'm kinda confused since i'm new to angularjs

Answer (score 0):

> I'm finding it hard to put the second js into the first one. I'm kinda confused since i'm new to angularjs

It sounds like you're trying to break up your app into separate JS files. Taking a tip from the [Angular 1.x [Code] Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules) on how you should break up your app, I would create a singular module *setter* file where you define the module and declare any module dependencies.

#### module.js

```
angular.module( 'app', [ ... ])
```

#### controller.js

So you're 1st and 2nd scripts are for the same controller as best I can tell.  You do need to settle on one name or the other.  I recommend 'Shops' as that is a standard naming convention for angular controllers.  Just combine them like so:

```
angular.module( 'app' )
.controller( 'Shops', [
    '$scope','$http','$timeout',
    function( $scope, $http, $timeout ){
        $http.get('http://localhost/moves/templates/shopping.php')
        .success(function(data){ .... })


        $scope.pushNotification = {};
        $scope.pushNotification.text = "Sample"
        $scope.pushNotification.checked = false;

        $scope.pushNotificationChange = function(item) {
               console.log('Push Notification Change',         $scope.pushNotification.checked);
            if($scope.pushNotification.checked){
                localStorage.setItem("shop_id",($scope.item.shop_id));
            }else{
                localStorage.removeItem("shop_id");
            }
        }


         $scope.shops = [
          { shop_id: 1, shop_name: 'Shop One', checked: false },
          { shop_id: 1, shop_name: 'Shop One', checked: false },
          ...
         ]

         $scope.onItemChange = function(item) { ... }
```

Lastly you need to be sure to declare your module.js before your controller.js.  I highly recommend a few things to you, seeing as you are new to Angular:

- start using the *controller-as* syntax
- start following some of the conventions outlined in that style guide.

I say this because if you plan to move to Angular 2 at some point, being well-practiced in these conventions will ease the migration process.

Comment: i'm quiet confused with the answer so i've updated the question to the current state to where what it only does is to save to localstorage when its turn on. can you please help me to do what i asked earlier, by turning one off if new one is switch on

Answer (score 0):

**note:** You've edited your question enough that my prior answer isn't valid in any way.

Your toggle UX can easily be addressed with Angular's native [*input[radio]* implementation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).  You need to simply define two inputs using both `ngModel` and `ngValue` on each input:

```
<input type="radio" 
       ng-model="vm.selected" 
       ng-value="'foo'"/>

<input type="radio" 
       ng-model="vm.selected" 
       ng-value="'bar'"/>
```

You can also use `ng-change` to trigger the `active_shop` function:

```
<input type="radio" 
       ng-model="vm.selected" 
       ng-value="'foo'" 
       ng-change="active_shop();"/>
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/KrLmqN)

The other option is to utilize [ui.bootstrap's radio button implementation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons) (if you're indeed using Bootstrap to style your app.

Comment: just checked your answer and it worked but mine is still not working. i wish we could move to a chat room and chat more about it. i'm using ionic as the UI

Comment: I haven't used Ionic so I'm unfamiliar with their directives and how to implement this feature into angular. Don't they have pretty substantial docs online?

Comment: i will check it out. please can you look into this question for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074996/infinite-scrolling-with-angularjs-and-php