# place localstorage value in a textbox from a controller with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a localstorage value which i would want to put in it a texfield from a controller

```
.controller('working_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http,$location) {
     $scope.user= localStorage.getItem("user")
     $scope.items = [];
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url:'http://localhost/work/templates/spree/work/items.php'
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data.data;
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  })        
}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="working_ctrl" ng-repeat="s in items| limitTo:1">
<input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" ng-model="s.quantity">
<input name="user" type="text" id="user" ng-model="s.user">
</div>
```

Comment: Try `<input name="user" type="text" id="user" ng-model="user">`

Comment: Yeah, Hardik Vaghani is probably right. `s` isn’t a rereference to your controller’s scope but to the current item `in items` you are iterating. So `s.user` addresses a property `user` in the current item instead of the controller’s scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the `$scope.user` to that textbox

```
<input name="user" type="text" id="user" ng-model="user">
```

Comment: thanks it worked. please can you take a look at this question for me please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858112/auto-switch-toggle-off-if-one-is-currently-on

Comment: dont use ng-model="user" with in ng-repeate .. it will create same ng-model multiple time  so use like this  <div ng-controller="working_ctrl" ng-repeat="s in items| limitTo:1">
<input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" ng-model="s.quantity">
<input name="user" type="text" id="user" ng-model="s.user">
</div>  this is correct

Answer (score 0):

your try to put the user in User input field but your input field is present with in ng-repeat  so push user data in Array or set the user data in specific array index . like this

```
    .controller('working_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.user = localStorage.getItem("user")
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/work/templates/spree/work/items.php'
    }).then(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.data;
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        $scope.item.forEach(function(value) {
            value.user = $scope.user
        })
        or // 

        $scope.item[0].user = $scope.user // user specific index
    })
}])
```