# Live refresh when new data is inserted angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to get a live update of records when a new record is inserted into the db. when a new record is inserted i want the div containing the `item in cart` to refreshed

```
.controller('newitem_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://localhost/spree/work/items/item.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.cart = data;
    });

    $scope.newitem = function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<p>Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://localhost/work/scripts/new_payment.php", {
                'item': $scope.item
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data)
            }).error(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="newitem_ctrl">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="item_name" placeholder="Item Name" ng-model="item" />
        <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="newitem()">Add</button>
    </form>
    <div ng-repeat="item in cart">
        {{item.product_name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.
Add the item in the cart array when you get a success response from post call.

```
.controller('newitem_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost/spree/work/items/item.php').success(function(data){
                    $scope.cart=data;
                   });

                $scope.newitem=function() {
                $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
                event.preventDefault();
                    $scope.newItem = {'item':$scope.item}
                    $http.post("http://localhost/work/scripts/new_payment.php",
                    $scope.newItem)
                    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                         console.log(data);
                         $scope.model = {product_name: $scope.newItem};
                         $scope.cart.push($scope.model);
                    }).error(function(error){
                         console.error(error);
                    });
                    }

            }])
```

It will update the div because the bound array is changed

Comment: it doesn't update it lively to see results unless i refresh the page myself

Comment: You want when a new item is added then the div containing the items is refreshed. Right ?

Comment: Please tell what error you are getting while using this

Comment: @UmairFarooq: ah, i think, if you look at the view you can see that you don't have to push `$scope.newItem` to `cart`. wont `$scope.cart.push($scope.item);` do?

Comment: @naveen I have edited the code. I think its correct now

Comment: no. i think product_name is a property of `$scope.item` which makes more sense

Comment: {product_name: $scope.newItem} when we add this object into $scope.cart then it will behave as same as the currently objects are behaving.

Comment: @UmairFarooq,it stil now working when i click on the button i get a successful response from the server but the div doesn't refresh until i use the refresh key on the browser

Comment: @user6579134 check out my answer, You'll see that I'm calling inside .always() event. also pushing to cart is not good idea, what if the cart in serverside could change? so it's bad UX in case of user see that in cart there are 5 elements, but really server has got 1 element, it's better get full list of elements from server (angular will rerender it automatically).
bad thing that You cannot have some web socket thing to emit contents of basket from server to client as it changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/work/scripts/new_payment.php',
    data: { 'item': $scope.item }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    $scope.cart.push($scope.item);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Unrelated: `.success` and `.error` callbacks are obsolete. Use `.then`

Comment: seems like he is using old version of angular

Answer (score 0):

Because You're not using socket.io or something alike

And You're asking about:

> update of records when a new record is inserted into the db

I can only decide to continuously request the php script and get fresh data.

I've made additions to Your code.
So You can copy-paste it:

```
.controller('newitem_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  function getCart(currentScope) {
    $http
      .get('http://localhost/spree/work/items/item.php')
      .then(function(data) { // success
        currentScope.cart = data;
      })
      .catch(function(err) { // error
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(function() { // always
        // to not throttle browser and server with requests will wait for http request end 
        // and recall getCart again
        setTimeout(function() {
          getCart(currentScope);
        }, 5000); // 5 sec
      });
  }
  getCart($scope);

  $scope.newitem = function() {
    $ionicLoading
      .show({template: '<p>Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});

    event.preventDefault();
    $http
      .post("http://localhost/work/scripts/new_payment.php", {'item': $scope.item})
      .then(function(data, status, headers, config) { // success
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) { // error
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(function() { // always
        getCart($scope);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: i get this error $http.get(...).success(...).always is not a function
    at getCart

Comment: @user6579134 fixed it, can You try?

Comment: Now the error doesn't appear again but the CurrentScope.cart=data is not producting anything. i've using console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); to see if anything is return but is blank. Please when you are done can you check out his question for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858112/auto-switch-toggle-off-if-one-is-currently-on