# calculation in angularjs output fails with ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on an angular project where i perform calculations on the page. In the textfield where i put the final results, when i get it an `ng-model` that answer fails to load. When i take out the `ng-model`, the answer appears. 
But i want it working while it have an ng-model="total" because i will send the total value to the database. With the below script, it works

```
<input name="price" type="text"  id="price" ng-model="price">
<input name="quantity" type="text"  id="quantity"ng-model="price">
<input name="total" type="text"  id="total" value="{{.price*quantity}}">
```

But with this

```
 <input name="price" type="text"  id="price" ng-model="price">
    <input name="quantity" type="text"  id="quantity"ng-model="price">
    <input name="total" type="text"  id="total" value="{{.price*quantity}}" ng-model="total">
```

it fails to works. The answer doesn't appear in the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<input name="price" 
       type="text"
       ng-model="price" string-to-number>

<input name="quantity" 
       type="text"
       ng-model="quantity" string-to-number>

<span>{{ price * quantity }}</span>
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to put the calculated value into the 3rd input, but if you are, you'll want to use `ng-model-options` to tell the *total* ngModel that it's to treat that value as a getter/setter - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Also note the `string-to-number` directive.  You're dealing with strings in the input. So in order for interpolation to work, you **may** need to add those.

#### edit

here is a working example of how I *think* you were trying to allow an override on the calculated value.  You can enter another value in the total input and hit enter to see it working.  This uses the `ng-model-options` - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/XKQzzv

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked. Can you please look into this for me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858112/auto-switch-toggle-off-if-one-is-currently-on